# Client/Server communication in C programming

Tags: c, unix, network-programming

I'm trying to solve the following problem that appeared in one of my previous tests.

Q: Write a program for a TCP client and a TCP server, so that, any word sent from the client is echoed back by the serve. For example, if the client sends "University" the server replies with "University".

Now, below are the files, I wrote.

server:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<unistd.h>
 #include<arpa/inet.h>
 #include<sys/types.h>
 #include<netinet/in.h>
 #include<sys/socket.h>


#define MAX_LEN 100
#define PORTNUM 2300

int main( int argc , char * argv[] )
{
char msg[MAX_LEN + 1];
int len;

struct sockaddr_in dest;

struct sockaddr_in serv;

int mysocket;
socklen_t socket = sizeof ( struct sockaddr_in );
memset ( &serv , 0 , sizeof (serv));

serv.sin_family = AF_INET;

serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

serv.sin_port = htons (PORTNUM);

mysocket = socket (AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

bind (mysocket , (struct sockaddr*)&serv , sizeof (struct sockaddr));

listen (mysocket , 1);

int consocket = accept ( mysocket , (struct sockaddr *)&dest , &socksize);

while (consocket)
{
    printf("Incoming Connection from %s - Secding Welcome\n",inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));

    len = recv ( mysocket , msg , MAX_LEN , 0);
    msg[MAX_LEN] = '\0';

    printf("Received the text %s, echoing it back\n",msg);

    send( consocket , msg , len , 0 );

    close (consocket);

    consocket = accept (mysocket , (struct sockaddr *)&dest , &socksize);
}

close(mysocket);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Client:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>

#define PORTNUM 2300
#define MAX_LEN 100

int main( int argc , char * argv[] )
{
char msg[MAX_LEN + 1];
int len;
char buffer[MAX_LEN + 1];

struct sockaddr_in dest;

int mysocket = socket( AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

memset(&dest , 0 , sizeof(dest));

dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_LOOPBACK) ;
dest.sin_port = htons (PORTNUM);

connect ( mysocket , (struct sockaddr * )&dest , sizeof(struct sockaddr));

printf("Connected to the server, Please Enter your Message:\n");
scanf("%s",msg);

printf ("Sending the message : %s to the server.\nPlease wait....\n",msg);

send ( mysocket , msg , strlen(msg) , 0);

printf("The message has been sent.\nWaiting for the Server's reply....\n");

len = recv( mysocket , buffer , MAX_LEN , 0 );
buffer[len] = '\0';

printf("Received %s from the server.\n",buffer);

close(mysocket);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get the following error, when compiling:

```
cc -o assignserver assignserver.c
assignserver.c: In function ‘main’:
assignserver.c:32:20: error: called object ‘socket’ is not a function
assignserver.c:38:66: error: ‘socksize’ undeclared (first use in this function)
assignserver.c:38:66: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Now, I know that socksize variable is not defined in the file. But I overlooked it the last time and it worked for a one - way communication with no errors.

Working code:

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define PORTNUM 2300

int main ( int argc , char * argv[] )
{

    char * msg = "Hello World !\n";

    struct sockaddr_in dest;

    struct sockaddr_in serv;
    int mysocket;
    socklen_t socksize = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);
    memset ( &serv , 0 , sizeof (serv));

    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;

    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    serv.sin_port = htons (PORTNUM);

    mysocket = socket (AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

    bind ( mysocket , (struct sockaddr *)&serv , sizeof (struct sockaddr) );

    listen (mysocket , 1);

    int consocket = accept (mysocket , (struct sockaddr *)&dest , &socksize);

    while (consocket)
    {
        printf("Incoming connection from %s - sending Welcome\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
        send(consocket,msg,strlen(msg),0);

        close (consocket);

        consocket = accept (mysocket , (struct sockaddr *)&dest , &socksize);
    }

    close(mysocket);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

This is working perfectly fine. It just relays a message to clients that connect to it.
Can you please help find what the issue is? and why it worked the first time around ( in the second server code ).
Also, I would be really happy if you can point me to a tutorial of some sorts where I can learn just the network programming aspect of the c programming language. Thank you in advance.

Edit 1: Formatting issues.

Comment: `socklen_t socket = ...` rename that variable.

Comment: @wildplasser - well spotted! I was looking for a multiple definition too, but in the client code, where the error list is :(

Comment: here's some well commented socket programming code i had compiled if you would like to see https://github.com/arjun024/socketfun

Comment: @wildplasser, It fixed the error. Compiled successfully. However, I am unable to echo the message sent. It just returns a blank string. The server reads a blank string.

Comment: @MartinJames tagging you. I don't know how to edit comments.